# Radiation Problem Based on Stephan's Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

A spherical black body of radius r is kept inside another spherical black body of radius 2r.

The inner body is maintained at a temperature T.

Find out the temperature of the outer black body

Comment: Not really enough information unless the answer T is sufficient?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).